# How do I get the top region of an image when cropping with Rails and Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip, crop

So I have a Rails 3 app using Paperclip to crop images.

I have this code in my model for Photo:

```
 has_attached_file :thumbnail, PAPERCLIP_OPTIONS.merge(
    :styles => {:cropped => '300x250#'})
```

The resulting image that's generated creates a 300x250 image, however the crop seems to always start a good 50px or so below the top of the image (not a good thing for social networking when it cuts off the top of peoples heads).

I did some research and I'm thinking I need to supply a :convert_options key that coincides with the :cropped style. However, I don't know exactly what options to set (-gravity, -region, etc.)

Anybody have any thoughts. I know there are Imagemagick pros; I'm not one, lol.

Thanks!

Update:
I found this link..
http://forrst.com/posts/Customized_Cropping_with_Paperclip-7g6

Is this still valid or does somebody have a better easier way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's my favorite way to do it:

```
:styles => { :large => "", :medium => "", :thumb => ""},
    :convert_options => { 
        :large => "-gravity north -thumbnail 300x300^ -extent 300x300" ,
        :medium => "-gravity north -thumbnail 200x200^ -extent 200x200",
        :thumb => "-gravity north -thumbnail 100x100^ -extent 100x100"
    }
```

Note that instead of # you use ^ +  extent.

Gravity parameters are like on a map: north, northeast, east ...

Comment: You are amazing! I was looking for this forever. On to reprocessing all my production images :(

Comment: Thank you for posting how to do this instead of leaving a snarky comment about how this is documented in ImageMagick's documentation.